# Java Robot screenshot efficiency

Tags: java, screenshot, awtrobot

I want to create a little Piano Tiles bot. For this, I need 4 pixels. My question is when I´m using the Java Robot class to create the screenshot, would it be more efficient to take 4 separate screenshots (each 1 pixel) or one big screenshot (about 800 x 1 pixels). It probably won´t make such a huge difference, but I just wanna know.

Comment: 1) What is a Piano Tiles bot. 2) Your question doesn't make sense. First you say you need 4 pixels. Then you ask if you should take 4 screenshots of 1 pixel each which would be 4 pixels or one screenshot of 800 pixels. Why would you jump to 800 pixels if you only need 4? 3) the Robot class is slow. If this is your own application you can easily get the pixels of your own components much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Test it yourself:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
// Take 4 seperate screenshots
System.out.println("Time taken: " + (System.nanoTime() - start));
```

and

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
// Take one screenshot
System.out.println("Time taken: " + (System.nanoTime() - start));
```

Idealy, you would put these statements in a loop like this:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
for(int i = 0; i < aBigNumber; i++)
    // Take a screenshot / multiple screenshots
System.out.println("Time taken: " + (System.nanoTime() - start));
```

Comment: You should use that in a big loop with multiple repetitions, because single test of singular events might be off by a really huge factor, once the JVM gets 'accustomed' to those calls, e.g. loading the necessary libs and optimizing the allocations. Also, to add some answer to the original question, make sure to keep the screenshots in the RAM, that will increase efficiency by a lot.

Comment: @user85421 You have. ;) I've never done posts like this before, and then I do 2 in one day. Huh.
But what am I supposed to do? It's just good advise in my opinion. ;)
Grüße zurück.

Comment: @JayC667 That is correct, although I thought it would be obvious to run the test multiple times.